# How to achieve a faded reflection?

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to use the [reflector class](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/e0d7e315ce0a5ad61d3dce49f4cd2eb4dba62ff4/examples/js/objects/Reflector.js) to create a reflective surface like this, where the reflective object naturally fades away:

[image]

The default reflection is completely solid.

How can I achieve a natural-looking fade away? Also, is there a description for some of the options in the Reflector class like `clipBias` and `recursion`?

Comment: This might not be available out of the box. Are you handy with GLSL?

Comment: @pailhead No - at least not yet. Can you describe how GLSL would help solve this?

Comment: even advice on where to look at would be involved so ill try to give a high level overview as a answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets start with this:

> Also, is there a description for some of the options in the Reflector class like clipBias and recursion

No. Notice that the file you linked lives in the `/examples` folder and not the `/src`. This means that it's not part of three.js in any way other than:

> A person, used three.js to make an example, and pushed it to the main repo.

Unlike the core that is for the most part documented (it sometimes falls out of sync or could use more documentation) the docs do not cover examples. The most you might find are comments in the code.

I tried to tackle this in a [high level overview of three.js.](https://medium.com/@pailhead011/what-is-three-js-7a03d84d9489)

Next, if you expect something like:

```
myReflector.fadedReflections = true
```

It probably doesn't exist. First of, you're probably looking for some kind of `fresnel` effect, so maybe it has an option for that.

If it doesn't then the reflector class is fairly limited, but it probably does no more than it should.

The bulk of the work it needs to do is to figure out where the camera would be in the mirror, what would be seen from it, and to render it efficiently into a "render target" (a texture) so that the other materials can use it. Say if your floor consisted of 5 different parts, each with a different material property (gold, marble, wood...) they would all use the same reflection texture.

The way i see the problem is - built in `Material`s don't have a slot for this type of reflection. It has to be mapped onto an object in screen space, not UV, and it has to be somehow integrated in the lighting model.

For example if you want to use it on `MeshStandardMaterial` the "fade" becomes "super complex math that runs the PBR lights and reflections".

Three.js allows you to modify these shaders but it's also involved, [i wrote a whole article on it.](https://medium.com/@pailhead011/extending-three-js-materials-with-glsl-78ea7bbb9270)

If you want to define that "fade" yourself, and to fade this reflection is literally the only thing you need (no shadows, no PBR, no lights for that matter, etc.), you can write your own simple `THREE.ShaderMaterial` with GLSL.

```
varying vec2 vScreenSpace; //compute this and pass to pixel shader
varying vec3 vNormal; //we need  the normal vector to compute the effect
varying vec3 vViewSpace; //we need the point to eye vector for the effect
void main(){
  vNormal = normalMatrix * normal;
  vec4 viewPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position,1.);
  vViewSpace = -viewPosition.xyz;
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewPosition;
  vScreenSpace = gl_Position.xy * 0.5 + 0.5;
}
```

Fragment:

```
varying vec2 vScreenSpace;
varying vec3 vNormal; 
varying vec3 vViewSpace;
uniform sampler2D uMyReflection;
uniform float uMyFadeFactor;
void main(){
  vec4 reflection = texture2D(uMyReflection, vScreenSpace); //read the texture in screen space
  float ndv = dot(normalize(vNormal), normalize(vViewSpace));
  float fresnel = 1. - clamp(ndv,0.,1.);
  fresnel = pow(fresnel, uMyFadeFactor);

  gl_FragColor = reflection * fresnel;
}
```

So something along this line has to run somewhere if you want this effect to happen. This is a super simple faked "fresnel" so if you wanted this to blend well into a PBR material, this math would become far more complex.

You could test out snippets of GLSL in a simple shader and then inject them at appropriate places in the built in materials.

Comment: Very interesting - I was thinking about just adding a layer of fog to the Reflector mesh, but perhaps that won't work? Is your shader applied on top of the Reflector or does it replace the Reflector all together?

Comment: @zakdances `Fog` doesn't work that way. It's a depth-based effect which is applied similar to near/far clipping planes of the camera.

Comment: You can try modifying this: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/e0d7e315ce0a5ad61d3dce49f4cd2eb4dba62ff4/examples/js/objects/Reflector.js#L257